# Keep mobile browser from showing elements outside content bounds?

Tags: html, css

In order to illustrate my problem, take a look at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ECaD6/

Pretend that I have made this webpage where the center (dark grey) area is the main content of the page. The background of this content area is purposely a different color than the sides of the container that do not contain any content.

I have placed an image absolutely, so that it lies outside the bounds of the intended content area. This works and looks good on a desktop browser.

However, when viewed in a mobile browser, the user can zoom out on the page so that they see this:

[image]

I would like it if the browser could only zoom out only as wide as the content container. Is this possible? I could obviously put a `overflow-x:hidden` on the `div` but then it would actually cut off the soccer ball altogether.

Would be nice if the mobile browser could only zoom out this far:
[image]

I know that technically the image (in this case) is part of the 'content' since it's in the content div. I'm wondering if there are any layout or css tricks that could be used to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: you say that it looks nice in a desktop browser, but for me it looks the same like the "zoomed out mobile browser" ? I don´t really get your question, obviously you don´t want the ball to be cut of and you want the ball to be cut off at the same ?

Comment: Desktop browsers usually are much wider than the content of a page. As a result, you see the sides of the content and you see the whole soccer ball, which is fine. However, mobile browsers zoom automatically to fit the content. I'm trying to keep the soccer ball visible as it is on desktop but not be considered "content" on the mobile browser.

Comment: you could simply set content area to width: 120% and align the ball to the very right (float:right), but thats hacky because you have to take care youre content never gets into the invisible area and you dont have a fixed width, obviously you want to have to

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a [`meta` `device-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) tab to your header?

Comment: It doesn't really solve the problem. I essentially just need to the soccer ball image to bleed over the edge of the page but not be considered to be part of the content that the mobile browser will use to determine how wide to zoom to.

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag in the `<head>` of your page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Hmmm that doesn't really help. Maybe I'm not being clear on what I'm wanting.

Comment: Can you upload the content to a test url (not a jsfiddle) so that we can visit on our mobile devices? Might give us some insight & guide us to a solution.

Comment: From first glance, it looks like the issue is with your static footer rather than the actual truck image.

Comment: I can't really tell without being able to play with the code. Alternatively, you could use a media query based on device width to reset the absolute positioning on smaller devices. This would be a simple fix with CSS